# Jquery appendTo('body') makes multiple inserts when used with Greasemonkey

Tags: jquery, dom, greasemonkey, appendto

I've made an Greasemonkey script which uses jQuery `appendTo('body')`.
Everything is working fine but the HTML is also appended to other DOM elements like Google ads and gadgets on my igoogle page.

Is there something to fix this? I don't think some example code is necessary for this issue. Instead I've uploaded a picture that shows my problem:

[image: my igoogle page]

As you can see, my appended HTML shows up in many different places.

Comment: I should need something like appendTo parent body or something like that :-/

Comment: try something like `appendTo($('body')[0])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is caused by the fact that Greasemonkey treats each `frame` and `iframe` as its own page (which in a way, it is), and runs as the `@include`, `@exclude`, and/or `@match` directives indicate.
(Note that iframes without a `src` attribute are considered to be from the same URL as the base page.)

To stop a script from triggering on iframes, place this code near the top of your script:

```
if (window.top != window.self)  //-- Don't run on frames or iframes.
    return;
```

---

If you actually want to run on some iframes and not others, tune the `@include`, `@exclude`, and/or `@match` directives if possible, or link to the target page for help choosing a method to selectively block iframes.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are seeing your HTML appended to multiple items is most likely because of the existence of iframes  in the markup you are dealing with.

Each iFrame (an I suspect that the gadgets, ads are iFrames) have their own entire HTML structure complete with `<html></html>` and `<body></body>` tags.  When you `.appendTo('body')`, your script will append the content to any element that matches the `'body'` selector.

You'll want to give a more unique selector than `$('body')`.

---

What you might want to do is try using `$('body:first')` of some sort of other unique selector in addition to the generic `body` selector.  You might have to play with this a bit because you are depending on HTML that is not in your control - I assume you'd like your GM script to run on any page - so you are limited to the structure of that page.  There is no guarantee for example, that the `:first` `<body>` tag will be the correct one.

If you ask me, the one sure fire way to do this would be to iterate over all of the `<body>` elements that `$('body')` returns and for each one see if it has a parent element that is an Iframe.

Something like this -

```
var selectedElement = '';
$('body').each(function(index,elem){
  if ($(elem).closest('iframe').length){
    selectedElement = $(elem);
  }
});

if (selectedElement){
  // appendTo(selectedElement);
}
```

---

- I'm using the [`.each()` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to iterate over all the elements that match the given selector - in this case - `body`.
- I'm using the [`.closest()` function](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) here to navigate through all of the parent elements and find the ancestor that matches the given selector - in this case - `iframe`.

Comment: yes thank you, I know but how can I do that? What selector is more unique than $('body') and exists in all pages?

Comment: $('body:first') does not solve the issue. is there a list of selectors I could try? or maybe I have to select the body that is not in an iframe.

Comment: thank you again! i've tried your method but $(elem).closest('iframe').length is always returning 0 so selectedElement can't be populated with the correct body tag.

Comment: Your assumption of the cause is correct; you can remove the disclaimer.  The solution is a little much for most occasions though. ;)